# subcaption incompatible with backref option of hyperref

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, subcaption

I have a problem with the `subcaption` package.

It leads to backrefs to tables only being displayed as questionmarks.

#### Minimal working example

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@inproceedings{namespaces,
title = {Multiple instances of the global linux namespaces},
author = {Biederman, Eric},
booktitle = {Proceedings of the Linux Symposium},
year = {2006},
}
@MISC{kernel_2.4,
title = {Index of /pub/linux/kernel/v2.4},
author = {{The Linux Foundation}},
year = {2013},
}
@MISC{kernel_2.6,
title = {Index of /pub/linux/kernel/v2.6},
author = {{The Linux Foundation}},
year = {2014},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[backref]{hyperref}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Loranium}
Lorem Ipsum
\section{notable}
this works \cite{namespaces}.
\chapter{Ipsonium}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        A & B & C & D \\ \hline
        a & b & c & d \\ \hline
        a & b & c & d \cite{kernel_2.4} \\ \hline
        a & b & c & d \cite{kernel_2.6} \\ \hline
        a & b & c & d \cite{kernel_2.6} \\ \hline
        a & b & c & d \cite{kernel_2.6} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{ABCD}
    \label{tab:abcd}
\end{table}

\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `hyperref` should be the last package to be included in most cases

Comment: Do you want `backref` or `pagebackref`?

Answer (score 2):

The relevant option should be `backref=page`, as this inserts the correct links to the page.

In addition, the `hyperref` package should be loaded after the `subcaption` package, which is not needed in this minimal example at all.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{subcaption}



\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Loranium}
Lorem Ipsum
\section{notable}
this works \cite{namespaces}.
\chapter{Ipsonium}
\phantomsection
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        A & B & C & D \\ \hline
        a & b & c & d \\ \hline
        a & b & c & d \cite{kernel_2.4} \\ \hline
        a & b & c & d \cite{kernel_2.6} \\ \hline
        a & b & c & d \cite{kernel_2.6} \\ \hline
        a & b & c & d \cite{kernel_2.6} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{ABCD}
    \label{tab:abcd}
\end{table}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not `backref`, though.

Comment: @egreg: I edited my example since I remembered the `backref=page` option

Comment: I do not want backref=page.
I want the backwards references to be chapter based, not page based.

Since I have a PDF where the first few pages are not numbered (or numbered differently to be exact) it links to the wrong page anyways.

Changing it to make hyperref the last include did nothing.