# The 'backref' package and biblatex are incompatible

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, citing, back-referencing

Still new to LaTex and found this question appearing many times here ([link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383054/biblatex-error-incompatible-backref-package), [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606398/incompability-of-backref-with-biblatex), [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218580/subcaption-incompatible-with-backref-option-of-hyperref)), but still couldn't figure out a solution. It seems like the other SO questions had `pagebackref` or `hyperref` packages but I got neither.

```
\documentclass[research]{letinbiom} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

The only other thing I could think of is the fact that I had this code before:

```
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

But I removed it. I also removed any reference for `\href` with it.

I did find this line in a `.cls` file in the Latex folder from the publisher:

```
\RequirePackage[
%  pdfusetitle,
  pagebackref,
  colorlinks,
  allcolors=mainBlue
%  linkcolor=mainBlue,
%  citecolor=mainBlue,
%  filecolor=mainBlue,
%  urlcolor=mainBlue,
  ]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Where can we find the class `letinbiom.cls` that you are using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I couldn't find your class `letinbiom.cls` online, but the snippet

```
\RequirePackage[
%  pdfusetitle,
  pagebackref,
  colorlinks,
  allcolors=mainBlue
%  linkcolor=mainBlue,
%  citecolor=mainBlue,
%  filecolor=mainBlue,
%  urlcolor=mainBlue,
  ]{hyperref}
```

from that file you pointed out in the question can definitely produce the error you are asking about as the following MWE shows

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\RequirePackage[
%  pdfusetitle,
  pagebackref,
  colorlinks,
  allcolors=mainBlue
%  linkcolor=mainBlue,
%  citecolor=mainBlue,
%  filecolor=mainBlue,
%  urlcolor=mainBlue,
  ]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Specifically, the culprit is the `pagebackref,` option.

You *could* simply remove that option from the `hyperref` call in the `.cls` file. but that does not seem to be a good idea. I'm assuming that you are using this specific class for a reason, namely that you want to publish with this particular publisher. In absence of evidence to the contrary we should also assume that the publisher has coded the class in the way it is coded for some reason. If we change the class we could be breaking the desired output or the publisher's workflow.

The fact that the class is strictly incompatible with `biblatex` is a pretty strong reason not to use `biblatex` for your submission. Many publishers have author guidelines or example documents explaining how you should generate your bibliography. Follow those hints and do not assume you can use `biblatex` unless you are explicitly told to use `biblatex`. `biblatex` requires a very different workflow than standard `thebibliography`/classic BibTeX.

Comment: +1 for "The fact that the class is strictly incompatible with `biblatex` is a pretty strong reason not to use `biblatex` for your submission." :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and for finding the problem! Removing the `pagebackref` removed the error. To simplify things, this doesn't actually go to the publisher. The publisher shared these LaTex files with us (hence why you probably can't find the `.cls` class online) and has their own latex files that they apparently can't share. Anyway, this submission is going to an online free resource (arxiv) so the public can easily access it. I couldn't find any problems after removing the `pagebackref` option, but I'm also not sure what specifically to look for. Any suggestions? Not familiar with it

Comment: @Penguin arXiv uploads with `biblatex` have their own issues (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/358831/35864), so even if this instance of the document is not to be typeset by the publisher you may still want to consider going for BibTeX. (I'm assuming the article is still going to be published with this publisher, otherwise it makes little sense to use their custom class. In that case for consistency reasons it is probably better to use the same bibliography settings in all cases.) ....

Comment: ... Apart from that it is hard to say what to look out for. It is possible that the `pagebackref` option was the only thing that made your class incompatible with `biblatex`. But at the same time it is also possible that there is more. If there are no warnings or errors when you try to load `biblatex` and the citations and bibliography come out OK, you should be fine though.

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot for all the help! Seems like the `pagebackref` was the only problem. Submitted successfully : )